# AppRater DialogInterface.OnClickListener asking view

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am trying to add Rate my app dialogue to my app but in Dialouge.OnClickListener it is asking for view.
How to solve this?

```
public class AppRater {
private final static String APP_TITLE = "YOUR-APP-NAME";
private final static String APP_PNAME = "YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME";

private final static int DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT = 3;
private final static int LAUNCHES_UNTIL_PROMPT = 7;

public static void app_launched(Context mContext) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("apprater", 0);
    if (prefs.getBoolean("dontshowagain", false)) { return ; }

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    // Increment launch counter
    long launch_count = prefs.getLong("launch_count", 0) + 1;
    editor.putLong("launch_count", launch_count);

    // Get date of first launch
    Long date_firstLaunch = prefs.getLong("date_firstlaunch", 0);
    if (date_firstLaunch == 0) {
        date_firstLaunch = System.currentTimeMillis();
        editor.putLong("date_firstlaunch", date_firstLaunch);
    }

    // Wait at least n days before opening
    if (launch_count >= LAUNCHES_UNTIL_PROMPT) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= date_firstLaunch +
                (DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
            showRateDialog(mContext, editor);
        }
    }

    editor.commit();
}

public static void showRateDialog(final Context mContext, final SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    dialog.setTitle("Rate " + APP_TITLE);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
    tv.setText("If you enjoy using " + APP_TITLE + ", please take a moment to rate it. Thanks for your support!");
    tv.setWidth(240);
    tv.setPadding(4, 0, 4, 10);
    ll.addView(tv);

    Button b1 = new Button(mContext);
    b1.setText("Rate " + APP_TITLE);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + APP_PNAME)));
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ll.addView(b1);

    Button b2 = new Button(mContext);
    b2.setText("Remind me later");
    b2.setOnClickListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ll.addView(b2);

    Button b3 = new Button(mContext);
    b3.setText("No, thanks");
    b3.setOnClickListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (editor != null) {
                editor.putBoolean("dontshowagain", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ll.addView(b3);

    dialog.setContentView(ll);
    dialog.show();
}
}
```

The errors are only showing on **(View v)** everything else is good.
I tried changing `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` into `View.OnClickListener` but that too is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can u exaplain wt u exactly  looking for:
As per my site i think you want when the method called, you want a dialog with two buttons and a rating bar in it.
buttons : ok and cancel
rating bar:
 Create one xml named ccc.xml::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffee"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
>


<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Rate"
    android:id="@+id/rate"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Remind me Late"
        android:id="@+id/later"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="No Thanks.."
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/no" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And then write this where you want to call it:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dialog d=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            d.setContentView(R.layout.ccc);
            d.show();
            RatingBar rate=(RatingBar)d.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
            Button rt=(Button)d.findViewById(R.id.rate);
            Button later=(Button)d.findViewById(R.id.later);
            Button no=(Button)d.findViewById(R.id.no);
            rate.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                    //do here what & where you want to save the rating 
                }
            });
            rt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                // do what you want on rate button
                }
            });
            later.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // do what you want on Remind me later button
                }
            });
            no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     // do what you want on NO button
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

if you need any changes here pls reply...

Comment: Your Layout is good! can i pass the rating user gives on rating bar to play store?

Comment: Yeah you can store the rating in variable like:  txtRatingValue.setText(String.valueOf(rating)); in the ratingbar method

Comment: And one more alternative you can have::   
String rating=String.valueOf(ratingbar1.getRating());
use this line in RT button click event then no use of that ratingbar change listener at all.